# clang: -fsanitize=undefined with 128 integer operations (undefined reference to `__muloti4')

Tags: c, clang, linker-errors, sanitizer, ubsan

In clang, I run into linking error if the [Undefined Behavior Sanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html) (`-fsanitize=undefined`) when the program uses 128 bit integer. The linking errors complain about `__muloti4`:

```
$ cat example.c
__int128_t a;
int main (void) {
  a = a * a;
  return 0;
}

$ clang -fsanitize=undefined example.c 
/tmp/example-df4873.o: In function `main':
example.c:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `__muloti4'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

(Tested on Ubuntu 17.10 with clang 4.0.1.)

With gcc it works out of the box (`gcc -fsanitize=undefined example.c`).

What does work with clang is the following call, but I neither understand it fully (`--rtlib=compiler-rt`), nor does it look like to me:

```
clang -lgcc_s -lubsan --rtlib=compiler-rt -fsanitize=undefined /tmp/example.c
```

I found it by trial and error, but it feels wrong to use clang and link against some gcc library. Also explicitly linking against `ubsan` should not be necessary according to the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html).

Is this the correct way to get rid of the error, or is there a more robust solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [known problem](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=16404) (also see [this](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/295)). Libgcc (which clang links against by default) does not provide necessary symbols to sanitize 128-bit types so you need to ask clang to use compiler-rt runtime library instead.

Comment: When using `--rtlib=compiler-rt` I now get an error with missing libunwind symbols, is there a fix that works for both these issues?

Comment: @CodeMonkey you could try linking both runtimes by specifying both `--rtlib` and `-lgcc -lgcc_eh` but this may be unsafe. I'd check with compiler-rt maintainers why you unwind symbols are missing.